# Solving recurrence T(n) = T(n - 1) + T(n - 2) + T(n - 3) + .... + T(1)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, math, big-o, backtracking

I have a backtracking algorithm. The running time is given by below relation:

> T(n) = T(n - 1) + T(n - 2) + T(n - 3) + T(n - 4) + ... + T(1)
>
> T(1)=1

What would be the worst time complexity of this algorithm? Intuitively it looks O(n^n) to me. But I may be wrong. How to calculate it formally?

Comment: Maybe you could start by manually calculating the first few values?  `T(2) = T(1); T(3) =  T(2) + T(1); ....`

Comment: Hint: `T(n) = 2 * T(n-1)`, for `n > 2`.

Comment: Isn't it `T(2) = T(1) + T(1)` even? That kind-of ambiguous in the description.

Comment: I was also thinking that his part is ambiguous @UlrichEckhardt I assumed that `T(2) = 1` too since `T(0)` isn't given in thee relation. Either way, I don't think that it has any impact on the Big O time complexity.

Comment: O(n^n) cannot be right. Because you would have T(n) ~ (n-1)^(n-1) + (n-2)^(n-2) + lower powers. But the second term and following are negligible in from of the first and you would have T(n) ~ O(n^(n-1)), which is significantly different.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way: You could calculate the time complexity by expanding each of the additive terms and observe the pattern: 
T(n) 
= T(n-1) + T(n-2) + T(n-3) + ... + T(1) 
= (T(n-2) + T(n-3) + ... + T(1)) + T(n-2) + T(n-3) + ... + T(1) 
= 2T(n-2) + 2T(n-3) + ... + 2T(1)
= 4T(n-3) + ... + 4T(1) 
= 2^(k-1) T(n-k) + ... + 2^(k-1) T(1) 
= 2^(n-2) T(1) 
= 2^(n-2)

Answer (score 1):

```
T(n) = (T(1) + T(2) + ... + T(n-2)) + T(n-1)
     = T(n-1) + T(n-1)
     = 2T(n-1)
```

Thus `T(n) = c * 2^n`, where `c` is `T(1)/2`.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following:

```
T(1) = 1
T(2) = T(2-1) = T(1) = 1
T(3) = T(3-1) + T(3-2) = T(2) + T(1) = 2
T(4) = T(4-1) + T(4-2) + T(4-3) = T(3) + T(2) + T(1) = 2 + 1 + 1 = 4
T(5) = 4 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 8
T(6) = 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 16
...
```

From the above it follows by induction that `T(n) = 2*T(n-1)` with the base cases `T(1) = T(2) = 1`

We can further built on this saying that since `T(n) = 2*T(n-1)`, `T(n) = 2*2*T(n-2)`. It follows that `T(n) = (2^i)*T(n-i)` for `i < n-2` and `n > 2`.

So in terms of time complexity we get `O(2^n)`.

Note: Please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm not the very best with this stuff. My appologies in advance. I'm trying to learn myself.